# Angular UI Datepicker Limiting Days to One Month

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui

I'm using the [datepicker for AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker).

By default it lists the days from the previous month and the next month. [Here's a picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1ILL.png)

How do I make these days invisible. I'd like the first day to always be Sunday. So the days should be listed Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc on top of the columns.

Comment: Bit late, but answer to similar question/answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31581652/446030

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with css:

```
.text-muted {
  color: transparent;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/EOS6geIcM5KO6tBwlxZF

But, you probably need to make it more specific to avoid interfering with other bootstrap elements that may use `text-muted`.

**Update**
To go further and disable the now invisible days, you can customize the `disable` function that is referenced by `ng-disable` on each day.  For example:

```
$scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
  return date.getMonth() !== $scope.dt.getMonth();
};
```

This is overly simplistic, but works for the initial date and should get you started.

Comment: Really good idea! The only challenge is if the person goes ahead one month, they can still select the invisible text. So if they're forward one month and they choose the 30th day of the current month, even though it's invisible, the button will be pressed. I'm not seeing which part of the code is specifically for dates before and after the current month.

Comment: visibility: hidden produces the same problem.

Comment: ok, disabling is obviously a little different than original question.  but i have suggested a possible solution that may work with some research by you.

Answer (score 0):

I modified **day.html** creation code block in the angularUI file (in my case file name is **ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js**) 
hide the date button when dt.seconday is true. **ng-hide=\"dt.secondary\"**

updated code block looks like

```
    angular.module("template/datepicker/day.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/datepicker/day.html",
    "<table role=\"grid\" aria-labelledby=\"{{uniqueId}}-title\" aria-activedescendant=\"{{activeDateId}}\">\n" +
    "  <thead>\n" +
    "    <tr>\n" +
    "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left\" ng-click=\"move(-1)\" tabindex=\"-1\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></i></button></th>\n" +
    "      <th colspan=\"{{5 + showWeeks}}\"><button id=\"{{uniqueId}}-title\" role=\"heading\" aria-live=\"assertive\" aria-atomic=\"true\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\" ng-click=\"toggleMode()\" tabindex=\"-1\" style=\"width:100%;\"><strong>{{title}}</strong></button></th>\n" +
    "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right\" ng-click=\"move(1)\" tabindex=\"-1\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></i></button></th>\n" +
    "    </tr>\n" +
    "    <tr>\n" +
    "      <th ng-show=\"showWeeks\" class=\"text-center\"></th>\n" +
    "      <th ng-repeat=\"label in labels track by $index\" class=\"text-center\"><small aria-label=\"{{label.full}}\">{{label.abbr}}</small></th>\n" +
    "    </tr>\n" +
    "  </thead>\n" +
    "  <tbody>\n" +
    "    <tr ng-repeat=\"row in rows track by $index\">\n" +
    "      <td ng-show=\"showWeeks\" class=\"text-center h6\"><em>{{ weekNumbers[$index] }}</em></td>\n" +
    "      <td ng-repeat=\"dt in row track by dt.date\" class=\"text-center\" role=\"gridcell\" id=\"{{dt.uid}}\" aria-disabled=\"{{!!dt.disabled}}\">\n" +
    "        <button type=\"button\" style=\"width:100%;\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\" ng-class=\"{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}\" ng-click=\"select(dt.date)\" ng-disabled=\"dt.disabled\" ng-hide=\"dt.secondary\" tabindex=\"-1\"><span ng-class=\"{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}\">{{dt.label}}</span></button>\n" +
    "      </td>\n" +
    "    </tr>\n" +
    "  </tbody>\n" +
    "</table>\n" +
    "");
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a new class (btn-secon) to the button, if it is dt.secondary using the existing ng-class directive.
Then wrote css targetting this class to hide that button by setting display:none. The code of the button now will look as follows:

```
    <button type=\"button\" style=\"width:100%;\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\" ng-class=\"{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt), 'btn-secon': dt.secondary}\" ng-click=\"select(dt.date)\" ng-disabled=\"dt.disabled\" ng-hide=\"dt.secondary\" tabindex=\"-1\">
<span ng-class=\"{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}\">{{dt.label}}</span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
function hideDates(){
   var span = document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted");
   for(var i = 0; i<span.length;i++){
     span[i].parentNode.classList.add('remove-borders');
   }
}
Call hideDates() function on every Month change. You can hide the dates.
In css:
.remove-borders{
  border: none !important;
}
.text-muted{
  color:transparent;
}
table tr td button.remove-borders:hover,
table tr td button.remove-borders:active,
table tr td button.remove-borders:focus{
   background: #fff;
   color: #fff;
   pointer-events: none;
   outline: none;
}
```

This will remove the borders for the parentNode which is a Button. So It won't show the previous month & next month dates. Note that we are hiding the dates with the css only.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the custom class option which can take an expression that returns a string. It is passed the selected date and the mode. But within that you can use `this` to access pretty much anything that the datepicker uses internally.

```
<div uib-datepicker ng-model="$ctrl.selected" datepicker-options="{ customClass: $ctrl.getCustomClass }"></div>
```

then in your controller\component

```
getCustomClass (date, mode) {
  let customClass = '';
  if (mode === 'day') {
    let monthToCheck = date.getMonth();

    // 'this' refers to the datepicker's scope so you can get access to all it's goodies
    let activeMonth = this.datepicker.activeDate.getMonth();

    if (monthToCheck === activeMonth) {
       customClass = 'datepicker-day-current-month';
    }
  }

  return customClass;
}
```

And now in your site's css you can do something like this:

```
.uib-datepicker .uib-day:not(.datepicker-day-current-month) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```