# Angular UI Datepicker Limiting Days per month

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using using the angular datepicker:

`http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker`

Currently it is hardcoded to display 42 days or 6 weeks.

I would like to know how to overwrite (ie. angular decorator) this function in ui-bootstrap-0.13.1.js to display 4 weeks.

Here is the function:

```js
ctrl._refreshView = function() {
  var year = ctrl.activeDate.getFullYear(),
    month = ctrl.activeDate.getMonth(),
    firstDayOfMonth = new Date(year, month, 1),
    difference = ctrl.startingDay - firstDayOfMonth.getDay(),
    numDisplayedFromPreviousMonth = (difference > 0) ? 7 - difference : -difference,
    firstDate = new Date(firstDayOfMonth);

  if (numDisplayedFromPreviousMonth > 0) {
    firstDate.setDate(-numDisplayedFromPreviousMonth + 1);
  }

  // 42 is the number of days on a six-month calendar
  var days = getDates(firstDate, 42);
  for (var i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
    days[i] = angular.extend(ctrl.createDateObject(days[i], ctrl.formatDay), {
      secondary: days[i].getMonth() !== month,
      uid: scope.uniqueId + '-' + i
    });
  }

  scope.labels = new Array(7);
  for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    scope.labels[j] = {
      abbr: dateFilter(days[j].date, ctrl.formatDayHeader),
      full: dateFilter(days[j].date, 'EEEE')
    };
  }

  scope.title = dateFilter(ctrl.activeDate, ctrl.formatDayTitle);
  scope.rows = ctrl.split(days, 7);

  if (scope.showWeeks) {
    scope.weekNumbers = [];
    var thursdayIndex = (4 + 7 - ctrl.startingDay) % 7,
      numWeeks = scope.rows.length;
    for (var curWeek = 0; curWeek < numWeeks; curWeek++) {
      scope.weekNumbers.push(
        getISO8601WeekNumber(scope.rows[curWeek][thursdayIndex].date));
    }
  }
};
```

I've tried hard coding the 42 days to something smaller but it breaks the calender calculation. Just looking if anyone has extended this before?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to wrap  `_refreshView` within a new compile function wrapping the old link function, if you use decorator. Within your `ctrl._refreshView` wrapper, you can do something like:

```
directive.compile = function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    link.apply(this, arguments);

    var _refreshView = ctrl._refreshView;
    ctrl._refreshView = function() {
      _refreshView.apply(this, arguments);
      removeAnySecondaryOnlyRows(scope.rows);
    };

    removeAnySecondaryOnlyRows(scope.rows);
  };
};
```

And:

```
//Remove any rows that contain only 'secondary' dates (those from other months)
function removeAnySecondaryOnlyRows(rows) {
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i],
      areAllSecondary = false;

    //check the first and the last cell's .secondary property
    areAllSecondary = row[0].secondary && row[(row.length - 1)].secondary;

    if (areAllSecondary) {
      rows.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
}
```

And all together as a functioning snippet, including a custom template and some css to hide the 'secondary' days (those from a different month):

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .config(['$provide', Decorate])
    .controller("MainController", ['$scope', MainController]);

  function Decorate($provide) {

    //fix for Datepicker 'day mode' to show only rows with days from the current month
    $provide.decorator('daypickerDirective', ['$delegate', daypickerDirectiveDecorator]);

    function daypickerDirectiveDecorator($delegate) {
      var directive = $delegate[0],
        link = directive.link;

      // custom html template:
      directive.templateUrl = "common/directives/uiBootstrapDatepickerDay.tpl.html";

      directive.compile = function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          link.apply(this, arguments);

          var _refreshView = ctrl._refreshView;
          ctrl._refreshView = function() {
            _refreshView.apply(this, arguments);
            removeAnySecondaryOnlyRows(scope.rows);
          };

          removeAnySecondaryOnlyRows(scope.rows);
        };
      };

      return $delegate;
    }

    //Remove any rows that contain only 'secondary' dates (those from other months)
    function removeAnySecondaryOnlyRows(rows) {
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i],
          areAllSecondary = false;

        //check the first and the last cell's .secondary property
        areAllSecondary = row[0].secondary && row[(row.length - 1)].secondary;

        if (areAllSecondary) {
          rows.splice(i, 1);
          i--;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  }
})();
```

```css
/*
Example of hiding days from other months:
We've put a class of 'datepicker' on the element loading the datepicker directive,
and we've customised the day template to add an 'invis' class to the day's button if
it's a 'secondary' day (a day from another month).
*/

.datepicker .invis {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">

  <!--
   Modified day template to add an 'invis' class to secondary day buttons.
   This could/should be kept in a separate file (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26339919/446030)
   -->
  <script id="common/directives/uiBootstrapDatepickerDay.tpl.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <table role="grid" aria-labelledby="{{uniqueId}}-title" aria-activedescendant="{{activeDateId}}">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" ng-click="move(-1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
            </button>
          </th>
          <th colspan="{{5 + showWeeks}}">
            <button id="{{uniqueId}}-title" role="heading" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="toggleMode()" ng-disabled="datepickerMode === maxMode" tabindex="-1" style="width:100%;"><strong>{{title}}</strong>
            </button>
          </th>
          <th>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" ng-click="move(1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
            </button>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center"></th>
          <th ng-repeat="label in labels track by $index" class="text-center"><small aria-label="{{label.full}}">{{label.abbr}}</small>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
          <td ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center h6"><em>{{ weekNumbers[$index] }}</em>
          </td>
          <td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center" role="gridcell" id="{{dt.uid}}" ng-class="dt.customClass">
            <!--######## 'invis' class added in ng-class on the button: #######-->
            <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt), 'invis': dt.secondary}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}">{{dt.label}}</span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </script>

  <div>
    <strong>Selected date:</strong> {{dt.toDateString()}}
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
    <div datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well well-sm datepicker"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jct, I'll try it out. But i suspect just removing the rows will have affects on how the weeks / months are calculated, when moving forwards and backwards through time. Let you know how I go

Comment: I've added a functioning snippet at the bottom of the answer that includes the override as well as a custom template/css to make the secondary days invisible - this way it's only showing the days of the current month. I've had to inline the custom template into a script tag since I can't have multiple .html files in the snippet. Hopefully this helps with putting all the pieces together, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i represent [`ADMdtp`](https://github.com/AmirkabirDataMiners/ADM-dateTimePicker) module. It's pure AngularJs dateTimePicker with disabling pattern and other lots of greate options:

- completely synced with ngModel, so no need to destroy or manulay update dateTimePicker.
- advance range picker; make as many dateTimePicker as you want related together, and again no need to destroy or manualy update each dateTimePicker.
- disabing pattern; so easily you can disable any day(s) in week or month, like all weekends.
- transition on changing days. (of curse you can disable it in options)
- get full date details like date in UNIX format, Date format and year, month, day, hour and minute separately and ... by full-data attribute.
- ...

`<adm-dtp ng-model="date" full-data="date_full" options="disabled:['2016/1/20', '!i&i+1', '15d+2']"></adm-dtp>`